# Pause the execution of Nodejs Server from command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

I was in an interview and the interviewer asked me the following:

> You have a server written in Nodejs. What you want to do is enter something in the command line and the server stops responding to the requests. It's running but does not respond to requests anymore. How can you achieve this behavior?

Comment: 1. you can pause running scripts, in a CLI idk how probably dependent on what you use. 2. every object gets a copy ... 3. new lang feature or use getter and setters 

Unfortunately this isn't the place for this kind of question (don't ask multiple questions). Voting to close

Comment: Silly, but you could put in a `while(true)` to block forever.. poof, unresponsive server

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this behavior. The interviewer was likely trying to assess your problem-solving skills, not looking for a rote answer.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote that tho', this is the right place to ask, in my opinion. What were the other questions? Or that was the first and the final one? (And please don't post rules link or anything to prove that it should be downvoted, we are a community that should be wanting to help others; I for example didn't ask a question since years ago (?))

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't agree with you. This is an open-ended question, which is not the format for StackOverflow.

Comment: It's hard to ask about something that you have no idea about. And yes, I asked a question 2 moths ago (and answered it myself), you don't have to check that out. I checked that for ya:)

Comment: I retracted my close vote because the question was edited to a single question. I disagree that the question is too "open ended". (Although it could use some clarification on some of the portions)

Comment: This question invites discussion, not answers. Only the interviewer knows what they were expecting to hear during the interview. "How to interrupt NodeJS process via process signals?" would be a more appropriate question. The only answer here assumes that this is about Unix knowledge, what about Windows? What if the interviewer wanted to hear about iptables and network configurations? We don't know. This question is very open ended.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what your interviewer was asking about, was a basic unix knowledge. For example you could run:

`kill -STOP pid` or `KILL -TSTP pid` to suspend the process

`kill -CONT pid` to resume the process